# Inject Jenkins text parameter as environment variables

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that I would like to provide multiple environment variables using something like a text box in the 'Build with Parameters' stage.

Generally I have these variables at a node or in Properties Content and they don't need changing but for certain tests I need to set different environment variables. I looked into EnvInject and regular Properties but I was unable to get them to inject my text parameter which contained multiple variables, perhaps I had it poorly formatted though.

So is there any way I can set multiple environment variables at the build parameterization stage without editing the job every time I want to try out something new?

Comment: EnvInject is the way to go. What issue are you having with it?